# what does the http keep alive affect on tcp connection?

Tags: http, tcp, keep-alive

On http persistent there is a "keep alive" timer.

When the keep alive time is over , what happend?
the tcp connection will close? i don't think so because there is keep alive on tcp connection that exsist.

so what is the affect of "keep alive http timer"?

If i open http connection to url (TCP) on port 80 , 
the port of server will not be  free until the tcp connection will end.

so what if the http keep alive end?

I tried to understand that .

i will be happy if i get an official source to this .

thanks!

Comment: The TCP connection will be ended. Not sure what you mean by TCP keep alive. A connection can be closed willfully at any time.

Comment: @usr
on tcp there is keep alive timer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569970(v=vs.85).aspx
RFC 1122
that if no get any segment from user on this time the tcp connection will be ended

what i want to know, if the another time: http keep alive timer on presistent (1.0) if this timer will be ended the tcp connection  will be close?
i will be happy to see official source to this

Comment: TCP connections live forever if both sides choose to not send anything. An idle TCP connection can live forever. There is no timer ticking. TCP has a keep alive feature that does detect broken connections but it is opt in and it does not make sense to opt into it in an HTTP scenario. TCP keepalive therefore does not enter the equation in practice. This is not specified. But even if it was enabled it could only end the connection and not keep it alive. TCP keep alive only shortens the lifetime, it does not extend it.

Comment: `When the keep alive time is over , what happend? the tcp connection will close?` yes, what else could possibly happen?

Comment: @usr It depends on whether you're talking about HTTP keepalive or TCP keepalive. If the *HTTP* keepalive timer expires, the connection is closed. If it's TCP keepalive, which it doesn't seem to be although there is certainly some confusion, a keepalive packet is sent, and *if not responded to* the connection is *reset*.

Answer (score 2):

> On http persistent there is a "keep alive" timer.

Correct. Don't confuse it with TCP keepalive, which is a completely different thing (RFC 1122). I am here assuming you are talking about HTTP as per your text.

> When the keep alive time is over, what happened?

The connection will be closed by one peer or the other.

> the tcp connection will close?

Correct.

> I don't think so because there is keep alive on tcp connection that exist.

I don't know what this means.

> so what is the affect of "keep alive http timer"?

It closes open HTTP connections when the specified period of inactivity has expired.

> If i open http connection to url (TCP) on port 80 , the port of server will not be free until the tcp connection will end.

Incorrect. You can open many connections to the same listening port.

> so what if the http keep alive end?

The connection is closed. You've already asked that.

> I will be happy if I get an official source to this.

The official source for HTTP 1.1 is RFC 7230-5, the successors of RFC 2616.

Answer (score 1):

TCP level keepalive is done out of band, so there is no stream data associated with this.  This means applications using sockets don't see the effect of TCP keepalives, so an idle connection will still be closed by an http server or proxy.

Also, the interval for sending TCP keepalives is typically very long by default (hours).  You can find more information on the keepalive socket option [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551(v=vs.85).aspx)

HTTP doesn't allow a server to attempt to prompt a client to do something, so if the client doesn't use a connection, the only option is to close it or leave it open.  That is typically a configuration option in the server or proxy.